# How to expand binomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working on a few proofs and am missing how this algebra works....

So, how does one expand $(k+1)^3\,$? Can I use FOIL? What does it expand to?

And how to expand $(k+1)^5\,$?

Thanks!

Comment: look up Pascal's Triangle, and Binomial Theorem. Also no, you can't use FOIL, at very least you must use distributive property.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the entry [**Binomial Theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) in Wikipedia.

Putting $y = 1$, that will give you the tools you need to expand $(k+1)^3,\; (k+1)^5, \;$ and $\,(k + 1)^n\,$ for any non-negative integer $n$.

FOIL works fine for $(k + 1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1$

One can go a step further by distributing $(k+1)$ over $(k^2 + 2k + 1)$ to get $$(k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1) = (k + 1)^3.$$

But for large exponents, it's handy to know the pattern of coefficients that correspond to different powers of $k$ in the expansion of $(k+1)^n$: Pascal's triangle shows this handy relationship.

I'll include an animation and image of "[**Pascal's Triangle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)" which displays the coefficients of expansions of a *binomial* $(k + 1)$ (these coefficients are referred to as: [**binomial coefficients**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)): up to and including fourth and fifth degree binomials, respectively:

$\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image] $\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

$$\text{Each number in the triangle is the sum of the two directly above it.}$$

---

To see how this "plays out" in the expansion of $(x + 1)^n,\;0 \le n \le 6$:

$$(x + 1)^0 = \color{blue}{\bf{1}}$$
$$(x + 1)^1 = \color{blue}{\bf{1}}\cdot x +\color{blue}{\bf{1}}$$
$$(x + 1)^2 = \color{blue}{\bf{1}}\cdot x^2 + \color{blue}{\bf{2}}x + \color{blue}{\bf{1}}$$
$$(x+1)^3 = \color{blue}{\bf{1}}\cdot x^3 + \color{blue}{\bf{3}}x^2 + \color{blue}{\bf{3}}x + \color{blue}{\bf{1}}$$
$$(x+1)^4 = \color{blue}{\bf{1}}\cdot x^4 + \color{blue}{\bf{4}} x^3+ \color{blue}{\bf{6}}x^2 + \color{blue}{\bf{4}}x +\color{blue}{\bf{1}}$$
$$(x+1)^5 = \color{blue}{\bf{1}}\cdot x^5 + \color{blue}{\bf{5}}x^4 + \color{blue}{\bf{10}} x^3 + \color{blue}{\bf{10}} x^2 + \color{blue}{\bf{5}}x + \color{blue}{\bf{1}}$$
$$(x + 1)^6 = \color{blue}{\bf{1}}\cdot x^6 + \color{blue}{\bf{6}}x^5 +\color{blue}{\bf{15}}x^4 + \color{blue}{\bf{20}}x^3 +\color{blue}{\bf{15}}x^2 + \color{blue}{\bf{6}}x + \color{blue}{\bf{1}}$$
$${\bf{\vdots}}$$

Comment: Image source: Wikipedia, found at link to "Pascal's Triangle".

Comment: Nice animated GIF! The answer is good, too :-) (+1)

Comment: Thanks, @robjohn! It says more concisely, in animation, what would take a bit of explaining to write!

Comment: @amWhy: It is unbelievable!! Great!! I cannot say anything. Nothing such this can describe the problem soooo well. +10!

Comment: This is incredible! Perfect explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome, uswer56763!

Comment: It's a minor point, but you should be aware that about ten percent of the male population is colorblind to one degree or another. If you're going to use color in text, blue is the best choice, red less so. Of course, this isn't a problem with the animation.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, @RickDecker: I've changed from red to blue, and will keep your comment in mind, from here after.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "FOIL" twice.  You should get
$$
k^3+3k^2+3k+1.
$$
More generally,
$$
(a+b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b+3ab^2+ b^3.
$$

Please don't vacilate between lower-case $k$ and capital $K$ in mathematical notation.  Pick one and stick to it.  Mathematical notation is case sensitive.  Sometimes one uses lower-case $k$ and capital $K$ for **two different things in the same problem**, and you need to be clear about **which is which.**

But it would take a while to use FOIL to get
$$
(a+b)^9 = a^9+9a^8b+36a^7b^2+84a^6b^3+126a^5b^4+126a^4b^5+84a^3b^6+36a^2b^7+9ab^8+b^9.
$$
That's one reason to be aware of the binomial theorem, which explains the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Before you jump to the binomial theorem (still the best way to go, in general, for expressions of the form $(a+b)^n$), let's start at the beginning. You undoubtedly know that 
$$
(k+1)^3=(k+1)(k+1)(k+1)
$$
We'll start by expanding $(k+1)(k+1)$. You can use FOIL here so we have
$$
(k+1)(k+1)=k^2+2k+1
$$
We're two-thirds of the way to the answer. Now we have
$$
(k+1)^3=(k+1)(k^2+2k+1)
$$
and by the distributive property, namely that $(a+b)c=ac+bc$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
(k+1)^3=(k+1)(k^2+2k+1)&=(k)(k^2+2k+1)+(1)(k^2+2k+1)\\
               &=(k^3+2k^2+k)+(k^2+2k+1)\\
               &=k^3+3k^2+3k+1
\end{align}
$$
This will work for any positive integer exponent but, as Michael notes, you wouldn't want to do this for $(a+b)^n$.

Comment: @ user56763: From what Rick Decker posted you can see that $(k+1)^3 = (k+1)(k+1)(k+1)$ can be expanded in the following way. Write down all possible 3-fold products of the form $ABC,$ where $A$ is a choice of one of the terms in the first $(k+1)$ factor, $B$ is a choice of one of the terms in the second $(k+1)$ factor, and $C$ is a choice of one of the terms in the third $(k+1)$ factor. Then add the 8 products. Thus, among the things you'll add will be $(k)(k)(1)$ and $(1)(k)(k)$ and $(k)(1)(k).$ Note that there are 3 of these with exactly two $k$'s and exactly one $1,$ so you get $3k^2$ ...

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the binomial theorem, where y = 1.

Comment: This is very scant. Something more would be good: some explanation or at least a link to an article. Of course, an answer should be more than simply a link. Look at the other answers for examples.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to, but was having trouble typing out the math for a more exhaustive answer.